# Vue Js in production not displaying file correctly

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I just finished developing a Vue/Vuetify JS +Laravel API(back end). Now I am trying to move it to production mode (to a new server). I ran "npm run build" to generate the file for production. It worked fine command and I have committed the file. however, I am having behavior that I don't know what is happening. When I try to access the site it seems like it does not load my JS file in my app.blade.php file. Below is what I have in my blade. I have confirmed the files exist in the server(public folder). It only displays "**scripts**" on the page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">

<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content="IE=edge">
    <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <link rel=icon href=/favicon.ico>
    <title>vue-material-admin-full</title>
    <link href=/css/app.5ca87fdf.css rel=preload as=style>
    <link href=/css/hunk-vendors.ad1efc67.css rel=preload as=style>
    <link href=/js/app.2d64425d.js rel=preload as=script>
    <link href=/js/chunk-vendors.4fbac20a.js rel=preload as=script>
    <link href=/css/chunk-vendors.fbe3c9f7.css rel=stylesheet>
    <link href=/css/app.5ca87fdf.css rel=stylesheet>
</head>

<body><noscript><strong>We're sorry but vue-material-admin-full doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please
            enable it to continue.</strong></noscript>
    <div id=app></div><script src=/js/chunk-vendors.4fbac20a.js></script>___scripts____
</body>

</html>
```

Here is my vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  // chainWebpack: config => {
  //   config.plugins.delete('prefetch');
  // },
  "transpileDependencies": [
    "vuetify"
  ],
  publicPath: '/app/',
  outputDir: '../../public/',
  indexPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
  ? '/app'
  : '/'
}
```

Comment: #1 Are your web and api on different hosts or are you host the vue inside of the laravel api? #2 Are you open to host the web on another host? #3 attach us the web console log of the error #4 Why are you using app.blade.php? vue build has its own index.html

Comment: #1: they  are on. the same host.
#2: It has to be on the same host
#3: Will get
#4: not sure, I will change it to the index.html.

Comment: If vue build is hosted into the same host of your laravel, What is the url that uses your vue code to consume the api endpoints with ajax? Spas could be independently deployed check this https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/deploy-a-react-app-on-a-server

Comment: the  vue and the api is on. the same host. Yes I am making ajax requests to the same host but using the prefix "/api" for my routes to consume the API.

Comment: Just to determine that php or vue are the problem, start it with with an http server like: https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve or https://github.com/usil/nodeboot-spa-server Share us if vue page loads correctly

Comment: cant you show us your `console ` error?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use `<script>` tag to load .js file. So please replace your below code

```
<link href=/js/app.2d64425d.js rel=preload as=script>
<link href=/js/chunk-vendors.4fbac20a.js rel=preload as=script>
```

With

```
<script src=/js/app.2d64425d.js rel=preload></script>
<script src=/js/chunk-vendors.4fbac20a.js rel=preload></script>
```

Comment: thank you. that did.  good catch.

Answer (score 1):

After your production build is done, you need to link your js files, in the same order, as mentioned in the Official Laravel Docs.

Try again after adding these at the bottom of your app.blade.php file.

[Laravel - Compiling Assets](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix#vendor-extraction)

[image]